# I stopped receiving rep on a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, achievements-dialog

I posted [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/112937/31224) an hour ago.

At the time of writing this, it has 14 votes. When I check rep gained from it however, it only shows that I've gained 30, even though 14 * 5 = 70:

[image: Rep screenshot]

This is the only rep I've gotten on PPCG in the past day (besides 2 for accepting an answer), so I shouldn't have hit a rep limit.

The main site shows the same thing, so this isn't just a display bug in the Android app.

Comment: I see 14 votes on the question, and +70 in your [reputation tab](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31224/carcigenicate?tab=reputation). I suspect it's just a caching issue.

Comment: @ale Ahh, you're right. If I just go into the quick rep view at the top of the page, it still shows 30, but if I go into my profile, it shows the 70. Ok, well, that makes sense.

Comment: This is a known issue. The achievements dialog is currently not getting new reputation events. The reputation is being added and will still appear in your reputation history.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's a bug. It has nothing to do with caching, the events just aren't ever making it into the dialog.

Comment: [Related in MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345461)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry about that. Fixed now.

Details [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345461/strange-reputation-accounting-on-stack-overflow) on MSO.

Comment: Rofl. Well, that explains it. Thanks.